# Play Framework custom java extensions for template

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play Framework 1.2.5, and trying to use [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead of the usual java.util.Date. I am trying to implement a format method for use in my views.

The Play documentation says I can create my own [custom java extensions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/templates#Createcustomextensions)  for use in templates, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have followed the example in the docs to no avail.

My custom extension:

```
package ext;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import play.templates.JavaExtensions;

public class DateTimeExtensions extends JavaExtensions {

    public static String format(DateTime datetime, String format) {
        return datetime==null ? "" : datetime.toString(format);
    }
}
```

My template code:

```
${subProject?.startDate?.format('yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

And the error I am receiving:

> Exception raised was MissingMethodException : No signature of method: org.joda.time.DateTime.format() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [yyyy-MM-dd]

It looks like Play isn't detecting my custom extension as the documentation says it should. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Your extension class looks good to me. Did you restart your application? Maybe a `play clean` helps? Does this also occur when you don't check for `null` values with the `?.` operator?

Comment: @Carsten `play clean` worked for me, thanks. Post this as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extension class looks good to me. The [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/templates#Createcustomextensions) states that you have to restart your application for the extension to become active. If that doesn't work, try running [`play clean`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/cheatsheet/commandLine). Doing so deletes temporary files, including cached bytecode, which will hopefully resolve your issue.